# Amazon SimpleDB on scale

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am thinking of using amazon Simpledb as a queue to take some load off of my webservices. The requests are larger than 64k and i need fifo so i cant use SQS. I am wondering what the concurrent limits are on simpledb. can I have 10,000 clients all inserting a new row at roughly the same time?

any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely have issues with SimpleDb because of its 'eventual consistency' on writes. This means that when you write data, its not guaranteed to be returned in a query made immediately after. I've heard that you're safe after a couple of seconds, but you have to code the system to take this into account.

This has been mitigated slightly with the introduction of conditional puts, which ensures that there are no lost updates if there are concurrent writes. The eventual consistency model can make it quite complicated to code simple things like counters and queues.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/typica/source/browse/trunk/java/com/xerox/amazonws/sdb/Counter.java) is an example of a incrementing counter implimented in Java using the AWS SDK. Notice in the `nextValue` method:

```
while (!done) {
```

Clients essentially retry until their put is cleanly processed. This is not scalable!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think im going to cook up something else using s3 and a worker that uses the manifest to populate msmq on the server. From what I have read there are no limits on the qty of concurrent s3 object writes.

Comment: They used to charge for simpledb puts and gets (puts cost 10x more) so this was also a consideration, but these have disappeared from their pricing so I guess they've dropped them. Whenever I've started looking at simpledb I've ended up using s3 as a key/value store and either selecting keys intelligently or indexed locally.

Comment: Also note that s3 allows you to query buckets with a prefix. This can be great to search for dates by using a prefix: /yyyy/mm/dd/...

Comment: SimpleDB has supported consistent reads for some time now. This should solve the *former* problem of eventual consistency. http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/#consistent